HttpContext session data return null after published API from React App
I am using asp.net core web api for backend and React for frontend.I use HttpContext for session in api in post method.  when i published api, i can get response from postman for HttpContext  session. but from my React app HttpContext  session is null.

This is my middleware code. where i set session data.
 var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
 string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
 string serverSelection = null;

 // Check if serverSelection is provided in query string
 var queryServerSelection = context.Request.Query["serverSelection"].FirstOrDefault();
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryServerSelection))
 {
     serverSelection = queryServerSelection;
     connectionString = BuildConnectionString(serverSelection);

     // Save serverSelection and connection string in session
     context.Session.SetString("ServerSelection", serverSelection);
     context.Session.SetString("ConnectionString", connectionString);
 }
 else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
 {
     // Extract serverSelection from JWT token claims
     var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
     serverSelection = jwtToken?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "serverSelection")?.Value;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverSelection))
     {
         connectionString = BuildConnectionString(serverSelection);

         // Save serverSelection and connection string in session
         context.Session.SetString("ServerSelection", serverSelection);
         context.Session.SetString("ConnectionString", connectionString);
     }
 }
 else
 {
     // Retrieve serverSelection and connection string from session or cookies
     serverSelection = context.Session.GetString("ServerSelection");
     connectionString = context.Session.GetString("ConnectionString") ?? connectionString;

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverSelection) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Server selection or connection string not found in session or cookies.");
     }
 }

 // Store the final connection string in HttpContext.Items for downstream middleware/controllers
 context.Items["ConnectionString"] = connectionString;

 await _next(context);

This is my login post method where i return session data and get null.
 public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
 {
     var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session;
     return Ok(new { AccessToken = session.GetString("serverSelection") });

please remember, i got response from postmman. but can't from my react app.
My React App code:
export const userLoginApi = async (username: string, password: string) => {
 
 
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${api}Auth/Login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'include', // Include credentials (cookies) with the request
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }) // Pass the username and password in the request body
    });

    console.log('Login response:', response);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const data: LoginAuth = await response.json();
    console.log('Response data:', data); // Log the response data
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during login:", error);
    throw error;
  }
  
};

Add program.cs code below
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Ensure the configuration is being loaded
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<JwtContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// Dependency Injection
builder.Services.AddCustomServices(builder.Configuration);  // All dependency injections are here

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", policy => {
        policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173", "http://192.168.1.205")
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
              .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
              .AllowCredentials(); 
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"] ?? string.Empty))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".ERPWebApi.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; // Ensure SameSite is None for cross-site requests
});

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
} else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

app.UseSession(); 
app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseMiddleware<ConnectionStringMiddleware>(); // Register middleware here
app.UseMiddleware<CustomCorsMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseIpRateLimiting();

app.Run();



Are you getting any CORS-related errors in the browser console?

yes. i am. but i already add cors policy in my program.cs file

Then you either did not configure it correctly, or some other error occurring during the request processing breaks it. Provide a appropriate details, please.

@CBroe add program.cs code for better understanding

What errors are you getting? Please quote error messages verbatim.

@CBroe add error image also. please check

Not sure how you could get all those errors in one go - if the request is blocked due to missing CORS headers, then I don't see how you could also get a 500 response. But that internal server error likely has something to do with the whole thing, so go and figure out what caused that first of all.
